# Is there a way to auto plant seeds?

Tags: astroneer

I have had a pumpkin farm for the F.A.R.M event and while it is mostly automated i want to know if there's a way to auto plant and destroy the seeds so that it is completely automated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something that not many people know is you can use a logic pulse to plant seeds. My personal favorite was using a timed delay on a wireless repeater for full automation. Simply place one of those wireless repeaters and 2 timed repeaters on top of it with Both of them set to max length and set it off. This will fully automate the planting of seeds and uprooting of seeds

Comment: Can you expand on this? How does it work? What do you need for it?